# Parse arabic PDF to plain text

Tags: python, pdf, pdfbox, pypdf, apache-tika

I've got a problem with parsing Arabic PDF to plain text. I have tried Apache Tika, PDFBox (both in Java and Python) and a few less popular tools like PyPDF2 every time getting mixed order of of signs. For PDFBox I have used the hint from the documentation for RTL languages [link](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/textextraction.html) but it didn't work. 
The example is presented below:

Original PDF:
[image]

Generated text:
[image]

The order is changed in every line that Latin sings occurs. Has anyone faced similar problem and solved it?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Did you ever find any help with this?

Comment: Text extraction for Arabic is pretty hard. Please see https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/discussions/1547 + add examples that we can use (PDF + what you would expect as output). At pypdf, no core contributor speaks Arabic (or any other RTL language). That makes debugging super hard.